# Rails: Exporting to CSV failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I am attempting to export my data to a CSV file. This is my model:

```
def self.generate_csv(ids)
    CSV.generate({:col_sep => "\t"}) do |csv|
      csv << ['topfind terminus id','position','sequence','protein (uniprot ac)','topfind evidence ids']
      ids.each do |id|
        n = Nterm.find(id)       
        csv << [n.externalid,n.pos,n.protein.sequence[n.pos-1..n.pos+9],n.protein.ac,n.evidences.collect{|e| e.externalid}.join(':')]
      end
    end  
  end
```

And this is the controller for this model that calls this method:

```
  def show
     puts "id search: [#{params[:id]}]" 
     @output = Nterm.generate_csv(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.csv { send_data @output.as_csv }
     end
     p @output
  end
```

And this is my view:

```
<%= link_to "Export to CSV", {:method=> "show", :id => @nterm.map {|i| i.id }} %>
```

I'm not quite sure what to put on my show view in this case. How do I produce a CSV?

Comment: Try adding `:format => :csv` to your `link_to`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your view as following, use your route path for view action, instead of `id`, pass `ids` because its collection of ids not single id.

```
<%= link_to "Export to CSV", your_route_path(:format => :csv, :ids => @nterm.map {|i| i.id }}) %>
```

And slide changes need to your action as following, for receive `ids`

```
def show
 @output = Nterm.generate_csv(params[:ids])
 #your codes goes here 
end
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be making it better but then I got an error like this: 
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'to_csv' for #<String:0x0000000a57c1c8>):`
I think there might be something wrong with my model

Comment: I did not found any method like `to_csv` in your code, you can trace details form log. But I think no need to use `as_csv` called in your controller action, You can get `csv` only using `send_data @output`, because `@output` already hold `csv` data for you.

Comment: Ah yes, I changed `as_csv` into `to_csv` to see if that worked. But I took your suggestion just to remove it and it worked, thanks!

Comment: Welcome @user1385816 :)

Answer (score 0):

@rokibul-hasan already answered the question, but I would also suggest for you to make a single query to fetch all the objects:

`@objects = Nterm.find(ids)`

and to loop through these objects instead of calling `.find` on each ID because you are hitting the database for each record, which is unnecessary. So something like:

```
@objects.each do |object|
  csv << [object.externalid, object.pos, ...]
end
```